# Default CGridView Results using findAll

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.16 and am trying to use CGridView to display a list of search results. I need it to be able to filter through those too. Just like how the default `actionAdmin` function works.

Here is the code in my controller:

```
public function actionajaxResearchList()
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        {
            $year = $_POST['year'];
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->addCondition("year=:year");
            $criteria->params = array(':year' => $year, );
            $query = Abc::model()->findAll($criteria);

            if ($query===null)
                throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');
            $model=new Abc('search');
            $model->unsetAttributes();
            if(isset($_GET['Abc']))
                $model->attributes=$_GET['Abc'];

            $this->renderPartial('_view',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'query'=>$query
            ));

            Yii::app ()->end();
     }
}
```

And in my `_view.php` i have this

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'abc-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(        
                 'name'=>'photo',
                 'value'=> '$data->photo',
                 'type'=>'raw',
                 'filter'=>false, //remove filter search for photo's
        ),
        'id',
        'year',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

How do I get it to display my `$query` results?  Should I try with the filter capabilities, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Add your query in the `search()` model function.

Comment: @Criesto like this? `if (empty($_GET['year'])) $criteria->compare('year',$this->year,true);
  else $criteria->compare('year',$_GET['year'],true);` but the filter on the cgridview doesnt work? i load the whole cgridview table using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rough code, it should work I haven't tested it though:

**Controller Action:**

```
public function actionajaxResearchList()
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year'] != "") {
                $year = $_POST['year']; //sanitize and validate this
            } else {
                $year = ""; //sanitize and validate this
            }
            $model=new Abc('search');
            $model->unsetAttributes();
            if(isset($_GET['Abc']))
                $model->attributes=$_GET['Abc'];

            $this->renderPartial('_view',array(
                'model'=>$model,
                'year'=>$year // passing the year
            ));

            Yii::app ()->end();
     }
}
```

**_view.php:**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'abc-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search($year),// year from controller
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(        
                 'name'=>'photo',
                 'value'=> '$data->photo',
                 'type'=>'raw',
                 'filter'=>false, //remove filter search for photo's
        ),
        'id',
        'year',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

**Model Search:**

```
public function search($year)
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        ... 

        if($year != "") {
            $criteria->compare('year',$year);
            //$criteria->addSearchCondition('year',$year);
        } else {
            $criteria->compare('year',$this->year);
        }

        ...

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```